# Dynamic function docstring

Tags: python

I'd like to write a python function that has a dynamically created docstring.  In essence for a function `func()` I want `func.__doc__` to be a descriptor that calls a custom `__get__` function create the docstring on request.  Then `help(func)` should return the dynamically generated docstring.

The context here is to write a python package wrapping a large number of command line tools in an existing analysis package.  Each tool becomes a similarly named module function (created via function factory and inserted into the module namespace), with the function documentation and interface arguments dynamically generated via the analysis package.

Comment: I doubt this is possible as you cannot even subclass function type, not to mention somehow making `def` produce objects of your own type.

Comment: I want to do this on the fly because within the analysis package one can set parameter values for different tools and these parameters get remembered.  I want the function docstring to present the current parameter settings for that tool.  So when you ask for 'help(wrapped_tool)' it needs to query the analysis package on the fly and create the docstring at that time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do what you're looking to do, in the way you want to do it.

From your description it seems like you could do something like this:

```
for tool in find_tools():
    def __tool(*arg):
        validate_args(tool, args)
        return execute_tool(tool, args)
    __tool.__name__ = tool.name
    __tool.__doc__ = compile_docstring(tool)
    setattr(module, tool.name, __tool)
```

i.e. create the documentation string dynamically up-front when you create the function.
Is the a reason why the docstring has to be dynamic from one call to `__doc__` to the next?

Assuming there is, you'll have to wrap your function up in a class, using `__call__` to trigger the action.

But even then you've got a problem. When help() is called to find the docstring, it is called on the class, not the instance, so this kind of thing:

```
class ToolWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, tool):
        self.tool = tool 
        self.__name__ = tool.name
    def _get_doc(self):
        return compile_docstring(self.tool)
    __doc__ = property(_get_doc)
    def __call__(self, *args):
        validate_args(args)
        return execute_tool(tool, args)
```

won't work, because properties are instance, not class attributes. You can make the doc property work by having it on a metaclass, rather than the class itself

```
for tool in find_tools():
    # Build a custom meta-class to provide __doc__.
    class _ToolMetaclass(type):
        def _get_doc(self):
            return create_docstring(tool)
        __doc__ = property(_get_doc)

    # Build a callable class to wrap the tool.
    class _ToolWrapper(object):
        __metaclass__ = _ToolMetaclass
        def _get_doc(self):
            return create_docstring(tool)
        __doc__ = property(_get_doc)
        def __call__(self, *args):
            validate_args(tool, args)
            execute_tool(tool, args)

    # Add the tool to the module.
    setattr(module, tool.name, _ToolWrapper())
```

Now you can do

```
help(my_tool_name)
```

and get the custom docstring, or

```
my_tool_name.__doc__
```

for the same thing. The `__doc__` property is in the `_ToolWrapper` class is needed to trap the latter case.

Comment: I can't comment on someone else's post yet (newbie, and all), but I want to say that overloading help() isn't a great solution, because you can't guarantee that anywhere help() will be called will use your version rather than the default version. Relying on that kind of monkey patching, in my experience, leads to difficult to debug problems at a later date when an unexpected use-case arrives (such as a new documentation tool, or a user with an 'enhanced' ipython, or a GUI help in an IDE, etc, etc).

Comment: Excellent, this did the trick.  The first two code examples are just what I wrote before posting the question.  I agree that overloading help is not a great idea.

Comment: Just say no to monkey patching.

Answer (score 3):

*(Python 3 solution)*

You could make use of Python's duck typing to implement a dynamic string:

```
import time

def fn():
    pass

class mydoc( str ):
    def expandtabs( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        return "this is a dynamic strting created on {}".format( time.asctime() ).expandtabs( *args, **kwargs )

fn.__doc__ = mydoc()

help( fn )
```

**Caveats:**
This assumes that the `help` function is calling `.expandtabs` to get the text from the `__doc__` object, which works in Python 3.7. A more robust solution would implement the other `str` methods in order to have our duck continue acting like a duck even if the `help` method changes. Also note that our `mydoc` class derives from `str`, this is because `help`, somewhat atypically, enforces strong typing by asserting `isinstance(thing.__doc__, str)`. Like all solutions this is a bit hacky, but whether this is a problem largely depends on the full project requirements.

Answer (score -4):

Instead of messing with the function, why not write your own `help` function?

```
my_global=42

def help(func):
    print('%s: my_global=%s'%(func.func_name,my_global))        

def foo():
    pass

help(foo)
```

Comment: I agree with @Ian, the overloading of the `help` builtin is not a great idea, because you're never sure how it will be used elsewhere.


However, there could be an improved implementation that would wrap a switch between a custom and the default implementation.

Comment: This is bad practise, don't do this.