# Can a docstring be created dynamically during the function definition?

Tags: python, docstring

There is a small problem with the following code:

```
docs = {}

def register(func):
    docs[func] = func.__doc__
    return func

@register
def blue():
    """Color function."""
    pass

@register
def red():
    pass
red.__doc__ = blue.__doc__

print("docstring real:", red.__doc__)
print("docstring registered:", docs[red]) # None!
```

The `red` function gets its docstring from the `blue` function. But this happens **after** the decorator registers it.

I could add an optional argument to the `register` decorator, but this case is *not special enough*. It looks like I have to copy and paste the string. No problem with that ... except that I'm still wondering if there is an trivial fix that I have overlooked.

---

**UPDATE**: After realizing that `@decorator` is just a syntactic sugar I've found a workaround:

```
# @register
def red():
    pass
red.__doc__ = blue.__doc__
red = register(red)
```

This solves my problem.

The docstring is still created after the function definition. For an answer to the original question see the comment added by idjaw.

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693883/dynamic-function-docstring

Comment: Question:  why do you need the dictionary?  If you know the function, why can't you just use the `__doc__` attribute?

Comment: @cdarke All registered functions form an API. There is an associated help function, e.g. `get_help(function_name)` that needs such dict.

Comment: Is `function_name` a text string or the function name?  I still don't see why you need the dict.

Comment: @cdarke function_name is a string in the real application. The functions are defined in several modules. A dict or other storage is needed to aggregate them into a single API.

Comment: You can still get the function object from a string by inspecting the caller's namespace.

Comment: @cdarke 1. Only selected functions are part of the API. 2. There is more information to store and that information cannot be obtained by inspection